# How can I get the index of this element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I am trying to get the index of an element using jQuery to send to a PHP script.

**Here is my XHTML**

```
<form action="/accreditation/questions/" method="post" id="questions-form">
  <fieldset id="question-0">
    <legend>Question</legend>
    <h3>What colour is grass?</h3>    
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="0" id="radio-0-0" />
        <label for="radio-0-0">Green</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="1" id="radio-0-1" />
        <label for="radio-0-1">Red</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="answer[0]" value="2" id="radio-0-2" />
        <label for="radio-0-2">Orange</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="question-1">
    <legend>Question</legend>
    <h3>how old is alex</h3>    
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="0" id="radio-1-0" />
        <label for="radio-1-0">21</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="1" id="radio-1-1" />
        <label for="radio-1-1">11</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="2" id="radio-1-2" />
        <label for="radio-1-2">23</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I need to get the index of the fieldset elements. I am currently using this each iterator (which I'd like not to change because it has a lot of other functions inside it).

```js
$('#questions-form ul li').each(function() {
    qIndex = $('fieldset').index($('fieldset', $(this).parent()))
});
```

I'd like qIndex to be the index of fieldset relative to the form. For example, in this case I should have it equal to 0 and 1 (although there would be 6 values because it's looping through the list elements).

I have played around for a while and have been unable to get the correct index. I keep getting not found (-1).

If it helps, here is the code I'm using to get the list item's index relative to it's containing ul element.

```js
index = $('li', $(this).parent()).index(this);
```

#### What is wrong with my fieldset index grabbing code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `LI`'s parent is `UL`, not the `fieldset`.
I think this will set `qIndex` for you:

```js
qIndex = $('fieldset').index($(this).parents('fieldset'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also get the index using:

```js
$("form fieldset").each(function(I) { 
    console.log("fieldset index"+ I);
});
```