# How to clone a filtered jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load a XML document to jQuery using `$xml = $(xmldoc)`. Then I filter it via `$xml.filter('id="something"')`. When using `.index()` on the filtered xml, jQuery returns the index in the **original listing**, not in the **filtered listing**.

**Example:**

```
<xmlroot>
  <xmlnode id="1" color="blue" />
  <xmlnode id="2" color="orange" />
  <xmlnode id="3" color="blue" />
  <xmlnode id="4" color="orange" />
  <xmlnode id="5" color="blue" />
</xmlroot>

    vObject = $xml.filter('[color="orange"]'); //vObject should just receive the xmlnodes 2 and 4
    vResult = vObject.filter('[id="4"]').index();
```

vResult will always be 3, but it should be 1.

I know this jQuery behaviour is by design, but I need a solution to fill vObject with the filtered xml, not with all of the xml. I've tried all night and I'm out of ideas.

Would be very glad if one of the experts here could help.
Thanks!

Comment: I am not getting the same result as you are describing.  When I run the same code you have listed above I get vResult = 0.  `vObject.filter('[id="4"]').length` is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the index of an element within jQuery collection you should pass the element to the `index` method:

```
var vResult = vObject.index(vObject.filter('[id="4"]')); // 1    
           // vObject.index(vObject.filter('[id="2"]')); // 0
           // vObject.index(vObject.filter('[id="3"]')); // -1
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C9Nyg/

Comment: Right.  This line:  vObject.filter('[id="4"]').index();  is creating a new filtered object set but you are not using it.  You are getting the index of the existing non-filtered set.

Comment: @SteveWellens The line `vObject.filter('[id="4"]').index()` returns a number not an object, `vObject` is a jQuery object that has 2 elements, `[id="4"]` is the second element in the new set.

Comment: You're today's hero for me :-) THANK YOU!! Now I can go to sleep... To be honest, I don't know why it works, but it does... Will investigate this tomorrow.

Comment: I think I got it: In my original question, the xml is filtered twice: Once before assigning it to vObject using the "orange" filter, once after assigning using the "id=4" filter. I thought that the first filter is permanently applied when the collection is assigned to a new Object - but it is not. It seems that under the hood, jQuery keeps track of all selectors and only references the elements of the original unfiltered collection >> it's the same as writing `vObject = $("xmlnode").filter('[color="orange"]').filter('[id="4"]').index()` >> obviously returns index position BEFORE any filter.

Comment: continued... I need to take vObject (where the first filter IS applied) and pass the element I'm searching for as argument >> containerterm.index(searchterm) >> this functions exactly as JS .indexOf() and simply returns the position where the searchterm was found in the containerterm. The tricky part is that .index() without argument is documented to return the first element in the **containerterm** relative to its siblings >> I thought I would find the siblings AFTER the first filter, but I found all siblings before any filtering, because of jQuery's under-the-hood selector concatenation.

Comment: @MarkusDerflinger In JavaScript by storing an object in another variable that object is not cloned, now that variable is only a reference to that object, after using `filter` a new jQuery object is returned but the DOM objects that are within the jQuery objects are the same, now you are storing filtered DOM objects in another object(using `filter` method).

Comment: @undefined - "The line vObject.filter('[id="4"]').index() returns a number"  I know that.  But as everyone is pointing out, it is applied to the vObject set that is NOT filtered by [id="4"].

Comment: @SteveWellens That's not true, there are similar questions on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628967/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-this-element-with-jquery